# Oracle OSM - XQuery doesn't loop

Tags: oracle, xquery, oracle-osm

I'm using `OSM` 7.2.0.3 and I have cartridge with an `Order Recognition Rule`, with its `Order Data Rule` (inside Transformation tab)

In the ODR I have this XQuery code:

```
declare namespace im="http://xxx"; 
declare namespace xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

declare variable $ord :=  fn:root(.)/im:Order;

<_root>
  <Order>
  {
    for $moli in $ord/MainOrderLineItem
      return 
        $moli/LineItemAttributeInfo/LineItemAttribute
  }
 </Order>
</_root>
```

The XML input to the OSM is:

```
<ord:CreateOrder
    xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
    <im:Order xmlns:im="http://xxx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/sce/dictionary/BaseOrderCommonCartridge/DataDictionary_BaseOrderCommon ../dataDictionary/DataDictionary_BaseOrderCommon.xsd">

      <OrderHeader>
        <OrderID>12345</OrderID>
        <RevisionNumber>1</RevisionNumber>
      </OrderHeader>

      <MainOrderLineItem>
        <LineItemAttributeInfo>
          <LineItemAttribute>
            <AttributeID>1234</AttributeID>
          </LineItemAttribute>
        </LineItemAttributeInfo>
      </MainOrderLineItem>
      <MainOrderLineItem>
        <LineItemAttributeInfo>
          <LineItemAttribute>
            <AttributeID>5678</AttributeID>
          </LineItemAttribute>
        </LineItemAttributeInfo>
      </MainOrderLineItem>
      <MainOrderLineItem>
        <LineItemAttributeInfo>
          <LineItemAttribute>
            <AttributeID>abcd</AttributeID>
          </LineItemAttribute>
        </LineItemAttributeInfo>
      </MainOrderLineItem>

    </im:Order>
</ord:CreateOrder>
```

There are 3 occurences of `<MainOrderLineItem>`'s but the output is only 1:

```
<LineItemAttribute xmlns:im="http://xxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AttributeID>1234</AttributeID>
</LineItemAttributeInfo>
```

Why is it not looping?

Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: Your query and output don't seem to fit the output - where comes `<OrderLineItem/>` from? Anyway, the query itself looks fine - but I cannot tell you anything to Oracle. Your query could be abbreviated to `$ord/MainOrderLineItem/LineItemAttributeInfo/LineItemAttribute`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
declare variable $ord :=  fn:root(.)/im:Order;
```

Must be:

```
declare variable $ord :=  fn:root(.)/*/im:Order;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. When you submit an order XML to OSM, by default it looks for `<CreateOrder>`, `<CreateOrderBySpecification>`, `<GetOrder>`, `<CancelOrder>`, etc and removes that element. So what OSM processes is only elements that is `<CreateOrder>`'s children. Hence `fn:root(.)/im:Order;` is correct.

Comment: @WillSumekar, This question is tagged just as "xquery", so I posted a pure XQuery solution. Please, tag appropriately.

Comment: I wanted to tag this as xquery, oracle-osm but I didn't find oracle-osm or anything similar and I don't have the power to create a new tag. Besides, I'd mentioned OSM in my original question.

Comment: anyway, the question remains unanswered. Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late a reply, but most likely the issue was with node selection expression in the for statement. The correct way to select multiple MainOrderLineItems :

```
for $moli in $ord//MainOrderLineItem
```

Notice the double forward slashes after $ord

'/abcde' path expression selects the root element 'abcde'

'parent//abcde' path expression selects all the child elements named 'abcde' under parent

Since multiple MainOrderLineItem nodes are present, the path expression needs to include '//'

Answer (score 0):

I just used your XQuery and checked, it is fine. Try to print out the $ord variable in console to see what you are actually getting in OSM.

this is what I tried in any XQuery ide:

```
declare namespace im="http://xxx"; 

declare variable $ord1 := <ord:CreateOrder
    xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
    <im:Order xmlns:im="http://xxx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/sce/dictionary/BaseOrderCommonCartridge/DataDictionary_BaseOrderCommon ../dataDictionary/DataDictionary_BaseOrderCommon.xsd">

      <OrderHeader>
        <OrderID>12345</OrderID>
        <RevisionNumber>1</RevisionNumber>
      </OrderHeader>

      <MainOrderLineItem>
        <LineItemAttributeInfo>
          <LineItemAttribute>
            <AttributeID>1234</AttributeID>
          </LineItemAttribute>
        </LineItemAttributeInfo>
      </MainOrderLineItem>
      <MainOrderLineItem>
        <LineItemAttributeInfo>
          <LineItemAttribute>
            <AttributeID>5678</AttributeID>
          </LineItemAttribute>
        </LineItemAttributeInfo>
      </MainOrderLineItem>
      <MainOrderLineItem>
        <LineItemAttributeInfo>
          <LineItemAttribute>
            <AttributeID>abcd</AttributeID>
          </LineItemAttribute>
        </LineItemAttributeInfo>
      </MainOrderLineItem>
    </im:Order>
</ord:CreateOrder>;

let $ord := $ord1/im:Order

return
(
    for $moli in $ord/MainOrderLineItem
      return 
        $moli/LineItemAttributeInfo/LineItemAttribute
)
```

and the result is as expected only..

```
<LineItemAttribute xmlns:im="http://xxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
  <AttributeID>1234</AttributeID>
</LineItemAttribute>
<LineItemAttribute xmlns:im="http://xxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
  <AttributeID>5678</AttributeID>
</LineItemAttribute>
<LineItemAttribute xmlns:im="http://xxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
  <AttributeID>abcd</AttributeID>
</LineItemAttribute>
```